# select element certain distance from top of window

Tags: jquery

It's simple, though I'm having trouble. Multiple rows of an element with the same class (`.proj`) on the page. Each takes 100% width. I want the `div.proj` that is within 200 pixels of the top of the window to have a class `.focused`, and otherwise, if it isn't near the top, to have the class `.default`. The problem I'm having is singling out the one element.

This is where I am at this point, but it finds all elements `.proj` instead of just the one that I'm looking for. This is what I have so far, which isn't really working at all at this point.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var proj = $('.proj'),
        top = proj.offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    if (top < 200 && !proj.is('.default')){
        $(proj).removeClass('focused').addClass('default');
    }
    if (top > 200 && proj.is('.default')){
        $(proj).removeClass('default').addclass('focused');
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example works for *every* element of class `.proj` within the 200px range. For singling out a single element, it will work if your elements are of height >= 200px.
If not you should tell us which is the criterion to "single out" a single element (f.ex. the topmost?)
In the example the widths are not 100% but the concept is clear I hope

```
​$(window).scroll(checkScroll);

function checkScroll()
{
    $(".proj").each(function(i,e) {
            var tp = $(e).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
            $(e).toggleClass("focused",tp<200).toggleClass("default",tp>=200);
    });
}​​​​
```

Check JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/hnYnS/

Check also http://jsfiddle.net/hnYnS/2/ for a different approach that uses 100% width and checks range between 0 and 200px.

```
$(window).scroll(checkScroll);  
function checkScroll()
{
    $(".proj").each(function(i,e) {
            var tp = $(e).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
            var isOk = tp<200 && tp>=0;
            $(e).toggleClass("focused",isOk).toggleClass("default",!isOk);
        });
}​
```

Comment: The second one seems to be working how I want it, but can't get it to work on my project. Say, instead, that the .proj class has an attribute of .3 opacity, and the .focused has attribute of 1 opacity.. so any element that is close to the top is full opacity and anything else is .3. We'll get rid of `.default`. I'm having trouble getting that to work. You can see what I'm working with here: stevenacr.es/portfoliov9

Comment: For some reason it's breaking the javascript in my site. http://stevenacr.es/portfoliov9/    Uncaught syntax error, according to chrome...

Comment: Wow that's **weird**! In Chrome's console if I type my function from scratch in your site it's ok... if copied and pasted it's not!
I believe there must be some sort of invisible special character in your source code that ruins it all... try to re-edit the file from start.

Comment: Ah that was the case! I thought it might have been but I didn't retype the whole thing, just the last line. Okay so if you look at the staging page above, it does add the "focused" class to the second item, but doesn't remove it from the first one. I tried a few things but I'm not doing it right haha.

Comment: I see only tp<200 in the source, add `tp<200 && tp>0`

Comment: Fixed. I had to decrease the `>=0` to like -500, so that once you scroll 500px past a project, the next project is almost in full view and becomes full opacity. Did some fading with CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you've sorted it out! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I think you just want to swap you < and >

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
var proj = $('.proj'),
    top = proj.offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
if (top > 200 && !proj.is('.default')){
    $(proj).removeClass('focused').addClass('default');
}
if (top < 200 && proj.is('.default')){
    $(proj).removeClass('default').addclass('focused');
}  
});
```

If that doesn't fix it, you should create a jsfiddle for it so we can see exactly what's going on.